# How can i transfer a value in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a HTML-file and a PHP-file. The index.html transfers a value to the php script with AJAX. I want that the servo.php file writes every value that it gets from the index.html in the file /dev/servoblaster.

You can find the files here:

[HTML-file](http://pastebin.com/c7aWj0tu)

[PHP-file](http://pastebin.com/tXiv4WUp)

**Question:** In this example the Value that i want to transfer is P1-11=160. But i want that the value could be anything (and not to create a single switch for every value).

```
if( isset($_GET['dir']) ) {
    // $_GET['dir'] -> Direction (up|dn|lt|rt|stop)

    $handle = fopen("/dev/servoblaster", 'w');

            switch($_GET['dir']) {
                    case "P1-11=160":
                            fwrite($handle, "P1-11=160\n"); //write in /dev/servoblaster - P1-11=160
                            break;
            }

            fclose($handle);

    }
```

Comment: If you want it to be anything than why use a switch/case statement in the first place? Why not just write the value, `fwrite($handle,$_GET['dir'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a switch statement looking for the specific text that you write, do the following:

```
$handle = fopen("/dev/servoblaster", 'w');
fwrite($handle, $_GET['dir']."\n");
fclose($handle);
```

Hence the value you save could literally be anything you wrote initially in the input field in the html file.